# Creating a Fixed-Length Queue Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, queue

I know this is a basic question, I have limited knowledge in JS. Is there an alternative method to keep an array length fixed with queue feature. The array keep receiving data I want always to remove the first element of the array?

```
var a=Math.random;
var array=[];

if (array.length < 4) {
array.push(a);
} else {
array.shift();
}
console.log("array",array);
```

I was hoping if there is such thing as following:

```
var a=Math.random;
var array=[];
array.length=4
array.push(a);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: No, no native feature like that. You'd have to make something yourself or use a library with that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically got it in your first code block there, it just requires a slight adjustment of the logic. If it's a queue then you should always push the new number. You should then test if the length is greater than 4, and if it is, then use .shift() as you have done here to remove the first element.

Comment: I was thinking to shift the array without using if-statement?

Comment: i see, so if you want to truncate an array to its last four elements (or leave it unchanged if its length is 4 or less) you could use `array = array.slice(-4)`. No if statement.

Comment: I read about array.slice. So should I just pit array.slice at the which will keep my array length to 4

Comment: well I would put it in the same place you put `array.length=4` (not valid code since the length property is read-only) in your second code block ... except I guess the push statement should go before it, not after.